# How to delete property of object in lightning controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript-remoting

I have an object with some properties used in lightning controller and I want to delete one of its property itself as:

## Markup:

```
<aura:attribute name="objectTest" type="Object" access="global"/>
```

## Controller:

```
var objectTest= component.get('v.objectTest');
delete objectTest['End_Date__c'];
component.set('v.objectTest', objectTest);
```

Getting error as :

> Not able to delete property 'End_Date__c' of object objectTest.

How to delete any property of object in Lightning controller.

Comment: I tried and it's working fine. Can you add more code ? In you JS your using objectA which isn't the same name as the attribute you've added to your question, and there is no default value for it so as far as I can see your object doesn't have any value. How is it populated ? Where is End_Date__c coming from ?

Comment: @FabienTaillon : Yes, I corrected the variable name , it was a typo here. And My attribute does not have default value but the End_Date__c is coming from some logic somewhere else. I have verified that it does have this property and the property has a value to it. Let me re-verify this today...if it is working or not as its working for you.